# How to extract the ssl issuer name with openssl

Tags: openssl

I have tried various combinations of openssl commands in order to extract ***ONLY*** the name of the SSL issuer of a specific domain name but this was not possible. I have also made a research in order to found ready solution but I was not lucky.

I know the following command will provide us a lot of SSL cert information including the name of the ssl issuer:
`openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect example.com:443`

Is it possible with a simple openssl command to retrieve only the name of the ssl issuer(e.g. Let's Encrypt or DigiCert) by using only the domain name?

Comment: If Unix, this is basic: `openssl s_client  -connect host:port [-servername host] </dev/null 2>/dev/null | grep "^   i:"` will show all issuers in the chain as sent, which per standards _should_ be complete possibly excepting root. Add `| head -1` to get only the first, or replace the grep with something like `| sed -n "/^   i:/{p;q}"` depending on your sed or Unix version. _For OpenSSL below 1.1.1_ `-servername host` is needed with _some_ hosts to get the correct cert chain.

Comment: On anything, you can use a second openssl: `openssl s_client as above </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -issuer` (on Windows use NUL: instead of /dev/null). (This _always_ shows only the first level.)